# Principal branch of logarithm

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, logarithms

I need to compute $\log(1+i)$ and $\text{Log}(1+i)$, $\text{Log}$ meaning the principal branch.

What I do is to express $(1+i)$ in polar coordinates, then equate it with $$\sqrt {2}(\cos \pi/4+ i\sin \pi/4)= \sqrt{2}\mathrm{e}^{\frac{\pi i}{4}}$$

Is this true? Can I now take $\log \sqrt{2}\mathrm{e}^{\frac{\pi i}{4}}=\frac{\sqrt{2}\pi i}{4}$?

And now $\text{Log}(1+i)=\log|\sqrt{2}|+\frac {\pi i}{4}+ 2\pi k$?

Can someone please tell what is wrong with my computation? What I am really confused about is how different it is to compute the principal brach and the other

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you know what the principal branch is?

Comment: yes @Winther. It is $Log z=\log z+i\arg z$

Comment: Yes, with the addition that arg$(z)$ is the argument of $z$ that lies in $[-\pi,\pi]$ (at least that is the definition I remember). Now you can use this to determine the branch $k$ in your expression.

Comment: @Winther Is my computation true for both $\log$ and Log? I am confused how different their conputation should be

Comment: @Winther, a quick comment: typo - "that lies in $(-\pi,\pi ]$".... Without that restriction (no $-\pi$), Log would fail to be a single valued function...

Comment: Not quite. Either start with the general expression for $\log(z) = \log(|z|) + i\text{arg}(z) + 2\pi k i$ and then fix $k=0$ to get the principal branch or just do this directly to start with: Log$(z) = \log(|z|) + i\text{arg}(z)$

Comment: @peterag Thanks for the correction, that is correct.

Comment: then can I leave it at $\log(1+i)=\log\sqrt{2}$? @Winther

Comment: No you forgot about arg$(z)$ which is $\pi/4$ here so: Log$(1+i) = \log(|1+i|) + i\text{arg}(1+i) =  \log\sqrt{2} + \frac{i\pi}{4}$.

Comment: No, I mean, I am asked to find the value of small $\log(1+i)$. Can I say then that $\log (1+i)=\log \sqrt{2}$?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The complex logarithm $\log(z)$ is defined as the inverse function to the exponential function, i.e. it satisfies $e^{\log(z)} \equiv z$.  Since $re^{i\theta} = re^{i\theta + 2\pi k i}$ for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ we have that any choice of an integer $k$ in $$\log(re^{i\theta}) = \log(r) + i\theta + 2\pi k i$$ is a valid inverse to the complex exponential. The logarithm is therefore a multivalued function and each value of $k$ defines what we call a different branch of the logarithm. The $k$'th branch is usually defined such that $\text{Im}[\log(z)] \in (\pi(2k-1),\pi(2k+1)]$. The principal branch corresponds to the choice $k=0$ which means that we just have

$$\text{Log}(z) = \log(|z|) + i\text{arg}(z)$$

---

The general expression for $\log(1+i)$ is therefore the multivalued function

$$\log(1+i) = \log(|1+i|) + i\text{arg}(1+i) + 2\pi k i = \log\sqrt{2} + \frac{\pi i}{4} + 2\pi i k$$

The expression for the principal branch follows by taking $k=0$ in the expression above giving us

$$\text{Log}(1+i) = \log(|1+i|) + i\text{arg}(1+i) = \log\sqrt{2} + \frac{\pi i}{4}$$