# Coordinate representation of the map $e^{2\pi it}$ using an angle coordinate map

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

This is Example 2.13 (b) from Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds.

If the circle $\mathbb{S}^1$ is given its standard smooth structure, the map $\epsilon: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{S}^1$ defined by $\epsilon(t)=e^{2\pi it}$ is s mooth, because with respect to any angle coordinate $\theta$ for $\mathbb{S}^1$ it has a coordinate representation of the form $\hat{\epsilon}(t)=2\pi t+c$ for some constant $c$, as you can check.

Here $\theta$ is a function from some open subset $U \subset \mathbb{S}^1$ to $\mathbb{R}$ such that $e^{i\theta (z)}=z$ for all $z \in U$. So we have $\hat{\epsilon} = \theta \circ \epsilon$. I can't see why we have $\hat{\epsilon}(t)=2\pi t+c$ for some constant $c$ here. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, $e^{i\theta (z)}=z\implies \theta(z)=\ln z/i$.

Note, your $S^1$ sits in $\Bbb C$.

Now, we need a *branch of log*, because the complex logarithm is not a single valued function.  The principal branch can be assumed, for instance, in which case, we have $\ln z=\ln r +i\theta$, where $z=re^{i\theta}$.

In this case your $c$ will be $0$.  For a different branch of log, it will be $\ln z=\ln r+i\theta+2\pi ki$.  See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1475592/403337.

So let's compose and see what we get:  $\hat\epsilon(t)=\theta\circ\epsilon(t)=\theta(e^{2\pi i t})=\ln(e^{2\pi i t})/i=2\pi t+2\pi k =2\pi t+ c$, where $c=2\pi k $.